# Very strange null pointer issue

Tags: java, jsp, variables, pointers, null

Hoping someone can help me out with a really bizarre problem I am having.

In the code below, I am trying to print out the number that's passed in the request. Its a string called number.

```
String number = request.getParameter("number");
```

^ String

```
out.print(number);
```

^ Printing number

At the moment this is failing with a null pointer exception, however when I print out number.length() it prints the length.

The stack trace also says the null pointer is occuring on this line

```
JSONObject JSONOBJ = new JSONObject(APIResponse.Response);
```

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Thanks!

```
<%
if (request.getParameter("number") != null)
{

    String number = request.getParameter("number");
    if (number.matches("^[0-9]+"))
    {
%>

        <%
            ApiRequest APIRequest = new ApiRequest(
                            "/broadband/availability/" + number, "GET", null);

                    /*
                    COULD ALSO PASS POSTCODE BUT ONLY USING CLI FOR NOW
                     */

                    ApiClient APIClient = new ApiClient();
                    api.ApiResponse APIResponse = APIClient.send(APIRequest);

                    JSONObject JSONOBJ = new JSONObject(APIResponse.Response);

                    JSONArray JSONARR = JSONOBJ.getJSONArray("products");
        %>

                Services for 
                <%
                out.print(number);
            %>
```

Comment: What is `out` and where is it set?  (Also, are you using some framework that you didn't mention in the tags?  I don't know what all those `<%` thingies are.)

Comment: Sorry should've mentioned this is a JSP. Outside of <% %> is HTML. Out is the browser.

Comment: Have you tried trimming the `String`? `String number = request.getParameter("number"); number = (number != null) ? number.trim() : "0";`

Comment: are you sure your `APIResponse` is not null? could you check it?

Comment: Post the stack trace, and show the line numbers concerned. It is far from clear from your description exactly where these NPEs are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really getting an NPE on this line:

```
  JSONObject JSONOBJ = new JSONObject(APIResponse.Response);
```

then the only explanation is that `APIResponse` (yuck!!!) is `null`.  And that means that

```
  APIClient.send(APIRequest);
```

(yuck twice!!) is returning `null`.  What causes that cannot be determined without seeing the source code and/or javadocs to these `APIxxxx` classes.

---

That is the only evidence that you provided with sufficient specificity for an accurate diagnosis.

You also mentioned getting a NPE when printing a number.  But I suspect that isn't what is *really* happening.  (For a start, if the NPE occurs at the line your *said* it occurs at, then it is NOT printing a number at that point.)